# Automating a process for multiple CSV file

Tags: csv, automation

I've been looking around and couldn't find the answer so here it is.

I'm trying to look into a way for automating of changing the content of a CSV file into something else for machine learning purposes. I have the content of a single line like this:

`0, 0, 0, -2.3145, 5.567...... 65, 65, 125, 70.` 
(516 columns)

And trying to change it to this:

`0,
0,
-2.3145,
5.567
....
65,
65,
125,
70.` 
(516 rows)

So basically transposing the data from horizontal to vertical (single row to single column).

It's easily done using Excel but problem is I have 4000+ of the CSV file so it takes a lot of time.

On top of that, I have to get the first 512 rows and store it into a CSV of another folder adding the last 4 rows into another CSV of another folder while both files have the same name.

Eg: 
features(folder)
1.CSV
2.CSV
.....
4000+.CSV

labels(folder)
1.CSV
2.CSV
.....
4000+.CSV

Any suggestions on how I can speed things up? Tried writing my own program but I'm stumped on changing it from row to column. I've only managed to split the single CSV file to it's 4000+ pieces.

**EDIT:**

I've tested by putting the csv rows into an array and then storing the array into the csv where the code looks like this:

```
with open('FFTMIM16_512L1H1S0D0_1194.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

    print(your_list[0:512])
    print(your_list[512:516])
    print(your_list)

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fa:
    writer = csv.writer(fa)
    writer.writerows(your_list[0:511])

with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fb:
    writer = csv.writer(fb)
    writer.writerows(your_list[512:516])
```

It works but I just need to run it in a loop. A problem that I don't understand is that if I save the values from 0 to 512 on test.csv, it will show 512 counts of rows but when I store from 513 to 516 to test1.csv, it only shows three instead of four rows that I need. Changing fb content from 512 to 516 will work which doesn't make sense to me because the value of 512 in test.csv is 0 while test1.csv is 69. Why is that? From what I can understand is the index of the array, it starts from 0 to the place of number I need. Or is it not the case in python?

**EDIT 2:**

My new code is as follows:

```
import csv
import os
import glob
#import itertools

directory = input("INPUT FOLDER: ")
output1 = input("FEATURES FODLER: ")
output2 = input("LABELS FOLDER: ")
in_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')

for in_file in glob.glob(in_files):
    with open(in_file) as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        your_list = (reader)

        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(in_file))[0] + '.csv'

        with open(os.path.join(output1, filename), 'w', newline='') as output_file1:
                writer = csv.writer(output_file1)
                writer.writerow(your_list[0:512])

        with open(os.path.join(output2, filename), 'w', newline='' ) as output_file2:
                writer = csv.writer(output_file2)
                writer.writerow(your_list[512:516])
```

It shows the output as I wanted but now it stores apostrophes and braces eg. ['0.0'], ['2.321223'] as well. How do I remove these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't do it programatically if you have your 4000+ pieces, just write every piece in a new line?

In my opinion the easiest way, but not automatically, would be some editor like [Notepad ++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Here you can Replace "," by "\r\n" or if you want to keep the "," you replace it with ",\r\n".

If you want it automated i don't see a not programmatical way.

By the way... if you use python with numpy/scipy you can just use the [.transpose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)  function

*Edit to your comment:

what do you mean with  "split from the first to the 512"? If you want parts with the size 512 it would be something like:

```
new_array = []
temp_array = []
k = 0
for num in your_array: 
    temp_array.append(num)
    k += 1
    if k % 512 == 0:
       new_array.append(temp_array)
       k = 0
       temp_array = []

#to append the last block which might not be 512 sized
if len(temp_array) > 0:
    new_array.append(temp_array)

# Save Arrays
for i in len(new_array):
    saveToCsv(array = new_array[i], name="csv_"+str(i))
```

Your new_array would now be an array filled with 512 sized arrays.
Might be mistakes here, i did not test the code. To save you only need a function saveToCsf(array, name) which saves an array into a file.

Comment: I have never tried python so I'll see if I can do it. Thanks for the suggestions. I did see that method in Notepad++ before to which I thought it would be somewhat of a hassle instead of Excel where you can just right click and transpose. I really just have bad programming skills with read/write. That's why I've only done with .txt files but never doing something like this. Sorry for the trouble. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Oh god. I found python to be so much easier to do automation than java. Thank you.

Comment: Transposing works now.I just need to figure out how to split the rows from the first to the 512. Any suggestions to where I can look into it?

Comment: What I mean is that I have 516 lines. I'm trying to see if storing the values into array would allow me to store lines from 1 to 512 (512) to a second .csv file and from 513 to 516 (4 lines) to a third .csv file. I'm sorry if it's not that clear.

Comment: thats exactly  what the above code should do :) You just need to loop through your new array and save every array in a csv file. 'll update the code.

Comment: Haahaha It works! but now facing a problem is that when it stores, the value shows with braces and apostrophes like ['0.0']. How do I remove them?

Comment: Just write it value by value.